# Efficient way to convert collection to array of hashes for render json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Is there a more efficient way to map a collection of objects to an array of hashes?

```
def list
  @photos = []
  current_user.photos.each do |p|
    @photos << {
      id: p.id, label: p.name, url: p.uploaded_image.url(:small),
      size: p.uploaded_image_file_size
    }
  end
  render json: { results: @photos }.to_json
end
```

This seems a bit verbose but the structure it returns is required by the frontend.

**Update**

So `.map` is the preferred method then?

Comment: Your "Update" statement lacks context. It would be preferable to make it a comment on one of the answers that uses `map`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Don't do it in the contoller
2. Don't generate the json response with `map`, let's `as_json(*)` method do that for you.
3. Don't use `@` variable in the json render.
4. Don't use `{}.to_json` the `render json: {}` do it under the hood.

in the photo model.

```
def as_json(*)
  super(only: [:id], methods: [:label, :url, :size])
end
alias label name

def size
  uploaded_image_file_size
end    

def url
  uploaded_image.url(:small)
end
```

controller code.

```
def list
  render json: { results: current_user.photos }
end
```

Comment: This is probably the best since it keeps the MVC house in order.

Answer (score 1):

As a starting point, it should be closer to:

```
def list
  @photos = current_user.photos.map do |p|
    {
      id: p.id, label: p.name, url: p.uploaded_image.url(:small),
      size: p.uploaded_image_file_size
    }
  end
  render json: { results: @photos }
end
```

Just for fun, you *could* do something like:

```
class PhotoDecorator < SimpleDelegator

    def attributes
      %w(id label url size).each_with_object({}) do |attr, hsh|
        hsh[attr.to_sym] = send(attr)
      end
    end

    def label
      name 
    end

    def url
      uploaded_image.url(:small)
    end

    def size
      uploaded_image_file_size
    end

end
```

And then:

```
> @photos = current_user.photos.map{ |photo| PhotoDecorator.new(photo).attributes }
 => [{:id=>1, :label=>"some name", :url=>"http://www.my_photos.com/123", :size=>"256x256"}, {:id=>2, :label=>"some other name", :url=>"http://www.my_photos/243", :size=>"256x256"}]
```

Comment: Sorry. Sloppy late over here.

Answer (score 1):

Please try

```
def list
  @photos = current_user.photos.map { |p| { id: p.id, label: p.name, url: p.uploaded_image.url(:small), size: p.uploaded_image_file_size } }
  render json: { results: @photos }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do that like this

```
def array_list
  @photos = current_user.photos.map { |p| { id: 
  p.id, label: p.name, url: p.uploaded_image.url(:small), size: p.uploaded_image_file_size } }
  render json: { results: @photos }
end
```

Comment: It can be confusing to assign a method the name of one of Ruby's built-in methods (`map`).